# Catching a duplicate error from mongoose unique index and sending a res 409

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema where I define an email to be unique. When I insert a duplicate email I get a Mongoose error, which is what I expect, but I want to catch it and send a res.status(409) when that happens, and I can't do it.

I've tried to use the **mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation** library to change the error I receive and catch it but I'm still lost.

My schema:

```
'use strict';
const beautifyUnique = require('mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// create the schema

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const accountSchema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        unique: 'This email is already taken ({VALUE})',
      },
    password: String,
    createdAt: Date, 
    verification: {
      verificationCode: String,
      verifiedAt: Date,
    },
  });

accountSchema.plugin(beautifyUnique);
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);

module.exports = Account;
```

The error I'm trying to catch:

```
{ ValidationError: Validation failed
    at ValidationError.inspect (/home/danielromero/Desktop/foodtrack git clone/foodtrack-demo/backend_foodtrack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:59:24)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:453:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:193:10)
    at Object.formatWithOptions (util.js:165:18)
    at Console.(anonymous function) (console.js:188:15)
    at Console.log (console.js:199:31)
    at insertAccountIntoDatabase (/home/danielromero/Desktop/foodtrack git clone/foodtrack-demo/backend_foodtrack/webserver/controllers/account/create-account.js:36:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  errors:
   { email:
      { ValidatorError: This email is already taken (sapo@yopmail.com)
          at new ValidatorError (/home/danielromero/Desktop/foodtrack git clone/foodtrack-demo/backend_foodtrack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:29:11)
          at /home/danielromero/Desktop/foodtrack git clone/foodtrack-demo/backend_foodtrack/node_modules/mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation/index.js:150:39
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at /home/danielromero/Desktop/foodtrack git clone/foodtrack-demo/backend_foodtrack/node_modules/mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation/index.js:140:36
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
        message: 'This email is already taken (sapo@yopmail.com)',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'unique',
        path: 'email',
        value: 'sapo@yopmail.com',
        reason: undefined } },
  _message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

I just want to know how can I reference the ValidationError message, and tell my code in a middleware that when that happens it has to send a 409 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at your stack trace, you can see where the error is being thrown `at insertAccountIntoDatabase (/home/danielromero/Desktop/foodtrack git clone/foodtrack-demo/backend_foodtrack/webserver/controllers/account/create-account.js:36:13))`

You'll want to catch that error by having code (likely in your resource) that transforms that thrown error into an appropriate response. It will likely look vaguely like:

```
try {
  await Account.create(params);
} catch (err) {
  // You only want to catch errors that you know how to handle
  if (err.ValidationError) return res.status(409).send();
  // hopefully this will get caught by something in your middleware and turned into a 500 with helpful metrics & logging
  throw err;
}
```

Conceptually, you want to catch the error when it happens -- the code that you shared configures how the mongoose schema behaves, but you want to modify the place where it's used.

Comment: Yes! I was totally not seeing where it originated. That worked wonderfully, indeed the throw got caught by my middleware and turned into a 500. Thank you so much, I'm just starting with node and was so stuck with this dumb error. Cheers! :)